# python tkinter placing rectangle with bbox on canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, rectangles, tkinter-canvas

I have a new question about tkinter.
I have my function:

```
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50, width=5, outline='black', fill='gray40', tags=('rect'))
```

How I can place the created rectangle on the canvas with the bbox coordinates? I dont know how I can compare the functions I hope it is possible. I tried to hang it on the last section but it didn't worked.

The function is:

```
canvas.bbox()
```

Answer (score 1):

`canvas.bbox()` returns a list. You can use that list in a call to `canvas.create_rectangle()`.

Here's an example of a program that draws two ovals, then uses the result of `bbox` to draw a rectangle that surrounds both of them:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400, background='white')
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 50, 50, fill="red")
canvas.create_oval(30, 20, 80, 90, fill="blue")

bbox = canvas.bbox("all")
canvas.create_rectangle(bbox, outline="black")

root.mainloop()
```